# Where are redmine groups' names are stored?

Tags: redmine

I know about groups_users table, but it contains key values only, and where are textual groups' names are stored?
Is it yaml-file or config file maybe?
Or some hardcoded values?

Answer (score 3):

In Database, groups and users are the same (Stored in `users` table, with a type `User` or `Group`)

In Redmine architecture, there is a main object, `Principal`, which can either be a `User` or a `Group`.

Try `Principal.where(type: "Group")`.